# Что означает # в php?

Tags: php

Знаю,что очень глупый вопрос,но в инете не нашел никакой информации.

Comment: Все что идет после решетки и до перевода строки это комментарий, он не участвует в работе программы

Comment: @Егор ни _не смог_, а _не захотел_ найти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень странно что не нашли. Пожалуйста: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.comments.php

Comment: Ну простой запрос в гугле 'php #' не дает никаких результатов,а в доках при запросе '#' тоже ничего нет

Comment: @Егор # -- не самое удачное ключевое слово. Лучше искать `php символ решётки` или `php hash symbol`

Comment: @ЕгорБанин `#` - это octothorpe.

Comment: @Suvitruf вы совершенно правы, но чтобы это узнать пришлось погуглить "как называется символ решётки" :-)